# plot with par(mfrow=c(3,2))

Tags: r, plot

I have data of 6 variables in excel (each variable in one column). But the length of each column is different.
I want to plot this data by `par(mfrow=c(3,2))` to divide the plot in 6 parts and plot all plots together ,but using the name of variable for each graph like the pic I attached.
The variable names are: `MKT  SMB   HML  RMW   CMA  MOM`
And the plot code is

```
MEplot(S,main = "variable name",cex.main=2,bty="n",cex.axis = 1.3,xlab = "", ylab = "")
```

I can plot the same photo, but I have to repeat code 6 times because the column name is different, so each time I have to specified the range of column and repeat the code.
Could you please help? How can I plot this graph with one code using for loop?

[image]

Comment: Are you actually using a function called `MEplot()`? We can’t tell because you didn’t include enough information for a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). As the link suggests, you should always provide any other `library()` that is part of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach using `base R`:

1. Set the plot parameters:

   ```
   par(mfrow = c(2,3))
   ```
2. Perform `for` loop for each variable:

   ```
   for(i in 1:6){
     plot(df[,i], main = names(df)[i], add = TRUE)
   }
   ```

Refine plot parameters as needed inside the `for` loop. If you want to have same-scaled y-axes, use `ylim = range(df)`.

[image]

Here's another approach using `ggplot2` (has the advantage that the y-scales are automatically aligned)

```
library(ggplot2)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = "", y = value)) + 
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(~ name)
```

If you want your 2 by 3 layout use `facet_wrap(~ name, nrow = 3)`(thanks to @r2evans!)
[image]

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  MKT = rnorm(100),
  SMB = rnorm(100,2),
  HML = rnorm(100,5),
  RMW = rnorm(100,60),
  CMA = rnorm(100,33),
  MOM = rnorm(100,100)
)
```

Comment: Since you're introducing `ggplot2` here, a more representative example (mimicking the original `3x2` plot) could be `facet_wrap(~ name, nrow = 3)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `lapply`.

```
par(mfrow=c(3, 2))
lapply(names(dat), \(x) plot(dat[[x]], main=x, xlab='', ylab='', ylim=range(dat)))
```

If you want to fill the layout column-wise, use `mfcol=` isntead of `mfrow=`. The `ylim=range(dat)` cares for the *y* axes to be in the same range.

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- setNames(as.data.frame(replicate(length(x), rnorm(100))), c("MKT", "SMB", "HML", "RMW", "CMA", "MOM"))
dat[] <- lapply(dat, sort)
```

[image]

Alternatively to `par` you can use a `layout` matrix.

```
layout(matrix(1:6, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE))
lapply(names(dat), \(x) plot(dat[[x]], main=x, xlab='', ylab='', ylim=range(dat)))
```